# Normalizing a Customer Satisfaction Index

Tags: survey

I'm looking to use the ACSI (American Customer Satisfaction Index) for a customer satisfaction survey. I'm confused by the explanation for how to calculate this. The survey is three questions:

1. What is your overall satisfaction with [our product or service]?
2. To what extent has [our product or service] met your expectations?
3. How well did [our product or service] compare with the ideal [type of offering]?*

And the explanation for the calculation is:

Some organizations simply normalize and average the three ratings, like this:
$$((Satisfaction-1) + (Expectancy-1) + (Performance – 1)) / 27 \cdot 100$$

I don't understand how this works -- why is 1 subtracted from each, and why divide by 27?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why subtract 1?** I assume that each measured on a 1 to *something* scale (probably 1, to 10), but they want to allow the minimum of each item to reflect *zero*. 1 to 10 minus 1 becomes 0 to 9.

**Why divide by 27?** The sum of the maximum score for each item equals 27 (I assume each item has the same maximum of 9 after subtracting 1, but they could have a different maximum, e.g. 7, 9 and 11). Dividing the score by 27 insures that you get a *proportion* as a result: a number between 0 (all three scores are zero) and 1 (all three scores are maximum). Then they multiply by 100 to represent that proportion as a percent.

Comment: Why would they want the minimum to reflect zero here?

Comment: Because the concept "None" obtains. Also: if my answer is satisfactory, do feel free to accept it (click the check-mark on the left) or to upvote it when/if you obtain upvote privileges. :)

Comment: Will do and thank you. I certainly understand the point here is to equate a "1" on the 1-10 scale with a "0," but I'm still not sure I understand why this would be preferable. What insight would this provide above and beyond having 1=1? Say each question received a response of 6. Using their equation would provide a score 55.55 as opposed to 60 (if we didn't subtract 1). What is more insightful about the 55.5?

Comment: Zero is the numerical concept of "none."

Comment: Also: 55.5 tells you 55.5%. If each score got 6, that would be 100* 18/27 = 66.7 (0.60), and that 67 would be mean "67 out of 11.111 to 100" which is far less intuitive than 55.5%.

Comment: If each score got a 6 using their equation: ((6-1)+(6-1)+(6-1))/27*100 = 55.5

Comment: If each score got a 6 using their equation: ((6-1)+(6-1)+(6-1))/27*100 = 55.5                                                    If each score got a 6 without subtracting one: (6+6+6)/30*100 = 60.0                                                                How is one of these more intuitive than the other?

Comment: Ah I see. 55.5 is 55.5% That is 55.5 out of 0 to 100. 60 is 60 out of 11.111 to 100. The former is a common enough way of thinking about proportions that just about every numerate human being on the planet does so (thinks in percentages) several times a day. The later exists only for this one example. That is how.